# How to change shutter speed on manual mode when movie setting is on?

Tags: dslr

I have Nikon d5200. And I am trying to shoot video in manual mode. Movie setting is set to `ON` from main menu. I can't record video until I switched to live view. And when I switched to live view, shutter speed of my camera sets to 1/50. I can increase the speed to 1/60, 1/80 and so on. But I can't slow it down to 1/40, 1/30 and so on.

Now if I set Movie settings `OFF`, I am able to change the shutter speed. But actually it doesn't change. I mean it shows on the screen that it is changed but in recorded video there is no change.

Is this the bug of Nikon d5200? Or am I missing some settings? Can it be resolved with some settings, tricks, or firmware update.

Comment: I can't even change aperture. :(

Comment: Off-topic as a video question... but you obviously can't set the shutter speed to less than 1/50s if you're shooting at 50 FPS.

Comment: There is a video stackexchange forum. You should post your question there.

Comment: Even if shooting video at 30fps the camera probably won't allow a "shutter" speed longer than about 1/50 second. This is because with only one sensor each frame has to be recorded and read out before the next frame can be recorded. If each frame is recorded for, say 1/5 second, then you would need multiple sensors and lenses to start a new frame 30 times per second.

Comment: @PhilipKendall That is ambiguous. The exposure time can be **no longer** than the frame time, but there's no *a priori* reason a camera can't take 1/2000 images at a 30 fps rate.  I'm hoping :-) you meant "no longer" when you wrote "less than"  .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Yes, I did. As an (ex-)physicist, this whole thing of describing a duration as a speed annoys me intensely :-(

Comment: @PhilipKendall well, as a (not-quite-ex)physicist, I fully commiserate with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your shutter speed would be slower than 1/50, you wouldn't be able to make a movie.

A movie is a sequence of (typically) 24 or 30 pictures ('frames') per second; so to be able to make 30 pictures, each picture can only take 1/30 of a second. Considering that the camera needs to do some processing and refreshing of the receptors, 1/50 is just enough time to make those 30 shots in second.

You can check if your camera has a time-lapse setting, which means you take less than 30 frames per second, then you might be able to set a slower shutter speed. However, the result might be unattractive because any moving objects would be smeared.